# What is the correct approach to pass the data from directive to sibling DOM?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

For animation reasons, I separated the directive and it's value in different HTML elements.

When the directive loads there, the separated element needs to update from the directive.  How can I pass the information from `directive` to other HTML element with same `controller`?

Example:

```
<div class="progName">
    <program-name app-name="appName" index='{{$index}}' ng-repeat="appName in appNames"></program-name> 
    <!-- the first directive as active one then.. -->
</div>

<div>Some other details goes here</div>
<div class="percent">
    {{appName.percent}}
    <!-- how to pass here -->
</div> 
<div>
    some footer information
</div>
```

In my scenario, whenever the user click on the directive, from the directive the `{{appName.percent}}` needs to update.

If I am not clear please comment.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/4/)

Comment: Can we see your directive and controller code?

Comment: You can pass the object from your controller into your custom directive scope and use two-way binding "=" .

Comment: @rsnorman15 - I given `live demo` please check.

Comment: @kwan245 - i can pass, but the object scope limits up to the directive right?  I require to pass the object data to sibling `dom`. i am looking for correct way to do that. can you update in demo?

Comment: @3gwebtrain , i dont understand why you using NgRepeat for image but no ngRepeat for the percent. Are you sure the percent is not child of ngRepeat ?

Comment: yes, the percent is not child of ngRepeat for animation purpose. otherwise as like you say, i need to put the `percent` in ng-repat and need to hide. since that's hidden, and the percent element replicate multiple times.

Comment: otherwise can i add the data to each of `directive` as like we add in `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to bind the controller's percent, add a two-way data binding to it so each directive can access it directly:

```
.directive('programName', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        appName: '=',
        index: '@',
        percent: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        var getTemplate = function (index) {
            return Number(index) ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{appName.name}} {{appName.company}}{{appName.percent}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="active que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{appName.name}}arif {{appName.company}}{{appName.percent}}</h2>';
        }
        element.html(getTemplate(scope.index));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.callMe = function () {
            $scope.percent = $scope.appName.percent;
        }
    }
}
```

And add the corresponding attribute:

```
<program-name app-name="appName" index='{{$index}}'
  ng-repeat="appName in appNames" percent="data.percent">
</program-name>
```

The controller simply defines the `percent` value inside an object, so the names do not collide with the child scope:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.appNames = [/* ... */];
  $scope.data = {
    percent: 22
  };
}
```

I strongly discourage using the `$rootScope`, since bi-directional communication avoids all this message handling and the coupling that it introduces.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5830xyL/)

Comment: No you are incrementing the percentage. i want to use the percentage what the `directive` has with that.

Comment: @3gwebtrain I understood the other way around, see my updated answer.

Comment: Nothing happend. the `directive` itself increments. be clear I require to pass the `percent` value from directive to percent DOM element on click of each `diective`. if not clear let me know.

Comment: have a look at `Md. Mahbubul Haque` answer. for further reference. still show me your way.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Ok, now I understand better what you want to achieve. See my updated answer.

Comment: it's great. sorry to as you sub question here.. how can  update the `active` text using clicked directive? I mean I want to update the clicked `directive` data to `active` directive and `active` data to clicked directive like interchange.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to communicate between two directives(pass data) that are siblings in DOM tree.

When two directives that are not in parent child relationship in DOM tree and you need to communicate between them, you can use $rootScope. And broadcast an event from $rootScope and recieve that event in another directive.

Just in one directive(from which you want to send data) inject $rootScope and use

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("eventName",attrs.valueYouWantToPass);
```

Then on another directive(at which  you want receive that passed data) you have to address this event. just use the following code snippet:

```
scope.$on('eventName', function (event, valueThatPassed) {
   //use this valueThatPassed to do what you want to do
   event.stopPropagation(); //stop the propagation so that the event doesn't propagate further
});
```

After checking your fiddle. I've simplified it. I've removed the other codes that are not needed to show the solve you exact problem. I've just changed it to a new fiddle where it changes the value of your directive element with the appName.percent value on click event of that directive. please check the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/obzy8s22/

Comment: Can you update in my fiddle please. actually I am trying to update in to DOM element not directive. but I can mange if I find the solution is right.

Comment: you can change dome element from your directive. let me check your fiddle first

Comment: @ 3gwebtrain : I've put a fiddle link on my answer. please check that fiddle, I've shown there how you can show the percent value of a dom element using directive.

Comment: Yes works. on load i require the `active` diretive data passed to element.

Comment: @Mahabubul, how to pass the template from a html file in angular way `
                            var getTemplate = function( index ) {
                               return Number(index) ? 
                                 '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{appName.title}} {{appName.percent}}</h2>' 
                                : 'public/viewes/active.html'
                             }`

Comment: use templateUrl: 'path/of/the/template/html/file' in directive definition and put your template code in that html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80259/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-md-mahbubul-haque).

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to hold the data and require the service on both directives. Then you can access the data at any time without passing it. The service can notify the directives when require.

```
app.service('shareData', function () {
  var UPDATE_EVENT = 'update',
  var REMOVE_EVENT = 'remove', 
  var listeners = {};
  var data = {};
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      if (listeners.hasOwnProperty(eventName)) {
        listeners[eventName].push(callback);
      } else {
       listeners[eventName] = [callback];
      }
    },
    set: function () {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        data[arguments[0]] = arguments[1];
        notify(UPDATE_EVENT + '.' + arguments[0]);
      }

      if (arguments.length === 1) {
        data = arguments[0];
        notify(UPDATE_EVENT);
      }

      if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw new Error('set method requires at least one parameter');
      }
    }
  };

  function notify (eventName) {
    if (!listeners.hasOwnProperty(eventName)) {
      throw new Error('No such event registered' + eventName );
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < listeners[eventName]; i++) {
     listeners[eventName][i]();
    } 
  } 

})
.directive('firstDirective'['shareData', function (shareData){
  return {
   link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
     shareData.on('update', function () {
       // Do your stuff
     });
   }
  };

}])
.directive('secondDirective'['shareData', function (shareData){
  return {
   link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
     element.bind('click', fucntion () {
       shareData.set({
         // change your data
       });
     });

   }
  };

}]);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0TPapNyqcUaowB0SuFsP?)

Comment: It's not possible to update in to jsfiddle using my demo? - if so that can be much help.

Comment: I haven't see your demo link but basically the structure is what i wrote then you should add your logic. I added the implementation  on a plunker